# Delete rows using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables that look like:

**offlineconversations**

```
userID | messageID

100      15
100      16
100      17
```

**messages**

```
messageID | sentBy | message               | ConvID
15          200      "Hi userID 100!"       hash
16          200      "Hi again 100!"        hash
17          300      "Hi I am user 300 :)"  hash
```

So here, UserID 100 received 3 messages, from user 200 and 300 (determined by `sentBy` in the `messages` table.

What I want to do, is deleted all rows in `offlineconversations`, where the message was sent by the user with id 200, so `sentBy` 200 in messages. The messageID in the `offlineconversations` table is associated with the messageID in `messages` Then offlineconversations would only be left with:

```
userID | messageID
100      17
```

So basically, delete from `offlineconversations` the rows where the userID is 100 and `sentBy` (200) is associated to them.

`convID` is used for the history aspects. If someone de-activates his account, the rows from `messages` should not be deleted. If the user deletes his account entirely, then the rows should be deleted from offlineconversations AND messages as well. That one I know I can do from cascading as someone pointed out in the comments.

Thanks

Comment: presumably you have a foreign key relationship between those two tables? a cascading delete would take care of this, e.g. deleting (15/200) in messages would delete (100/15) in offlineconversations as well.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to delete the actual messages from `messages`, as I will use it for history if the contacts decide to become friends again.

Comment: but if you delete (100/15) from offlineconversations, how could you re-associate that message with user 100? once 100/15 is gone, there'd be no recipient attached to messsage  15 anymore and no way to tell who it was sent to originally.

Comment: I omitted saying there is a `ConvID`column which each pair of 2 users share, that way when the user re-activates his account we can bring the messages back. But you're right about deleting. Deleting is not like de-activating, if someone deletes his account and someone else re-creates it and re-adds that initial same friend, then it brings issues.

Comment: that'd imply you're re-using IDs, then. This is one reason re-using IDs is a bad idea. A new account should get a new ID, then this problem becomes moot.

Comment: The history will only be re-used if someone re-activates his account. If someone deletes his account then deleting the rows in messages will be done as well. But for my activation/deactivation feature, I don't want to delete the rows from messages.

Comment: but why would you need to change/delete anything in the messages on deactivation then? presumably that'd just be a single flag field in a `users` table, e.g. `deactivated=1`. no deleting or anything, just a simple update 0 => 1.

Comment: why dont u add `sentTo` field to messages and not delete `offlineconversations` ?

Comment: I'm working with an old database and I'm refraining from changing its structure right now. @MarcB that's right I don't want to delete messages from `messages` in a couple of cases : if a user simply deactives his account, OR if a user deletes a user from his contact list. However I still want to delete the offlineconversations rows so that the user who deleted a contact doesn't even have to read those messages.

Comment: @DanyP, delete statement allows this, but be warn - if you have FK(with cascade) on `messageID` fields also messages rows will be deleted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query should work:

```
 DELETE t.* 
 FROM offlineconversations t 
 JOIN messages m 
 ON m.messageID = t.messageID 
 WHERE m.sentBy = 200 AND t.userID = 100;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8f70/2)

If you need to delete messages also:

```
 DELETE t.*,m.* 
 FROM offlineconversations t 
 JOIN messages m 
 ON m.messageID = t.messageID 
 WHERE m.sentBy = 200 AND t.userID=100;
```

[Fiidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c42e7a/2)

Comment: Let's say that user 200 also sent to users 101, 102, 103 etc. Will it not delete the rows associated with these other contacts as well?

Comment: you need Foreign keys for this, or `DELETE t.*, m.* ...` or even `DELETE *`

Comment: Does your query delete all rows sent (to anybody, not just user 100) by user 200 in both tables?

Comment: not only in `offlineconversations`, if you want both, write `DELETE *`

Comment: Err, when I wrote my 'basically' sentence I made a mistake, I should of said: So basically, delete from `offlineconversations` the rows where the userID is 100 and `sentBy` (200) is associated to them.

Comment: WHERE m.sentBy = 200 AND t.userID = 100; ill try now.

Comment: you can also write without `*` but I like asterisks, because it's very similar with `SELECT`

Answer (score 3):

what about :

```
    delete from offlineconversations where messageID in (select messageId from 
messages where sentBy = 200)
```